# Probability that at least one of the shifts will be unrepresented in the sample of workers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question**:

> A production facility employs $10$ workers on the day shift, $8$ workers on the swing shift, and $6$ workers on the graveyard shift. A quality control consultant is to select $6$ of these workers for in-depth interviews. Suppose the selection is made in such a way that any particular group of $6$ workers has the same chance of being selected as does any other group (drawing $6$ slips without replacement from among $24$). What is the probability that at least one of the shifts will be unrepresented in the sample of workers? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

**My confusion**:

> The answer is $1$ - (the number of combinations of 3 shifts being represented/total combinations). But how would you count all of these combinations where all $3$ shifts are represented? You could have a group of $6$ where $1$ person is from the day shift, $1$ is from the swing shift, & $4$ are from the graveyard shift. You could have a group of $6$ where $3$ people are from the day shift, $2$ are from the swing shift, & $1$ is from the graveyard shift. I do not know a method to counting all these combinations.

Comment: So what numbers did you get for the different parts of your Venn diagram? (you only really need to count the selections where all three shifts are represented, divide that by the total number, and subtract from $1$)

Comment: @Henry But how would you count all the selections where all 3 shifts are represented? You could have a group of 6 where 1 person is from the day shift, 1 is from the swing shift, & 4 are from the graveyard shift. You could have a group of 6 where 3 people are from the day shift, 2 are from the swing shift, & 1 is from the graveyard shift. I do not know a method to counting all these combinations.

Comment: The alternative is inclusion exclusion: find the numbers exclusively from one of groups, or from just two of the groups.  You can still use your Venn diagram if it helps.  What numbers have you calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want to know *how to count the number of combinations of 3 shifts being represented*.

We have the following cases:

#### 1. As $1,1,4:$

$=\binom {10}{1}\binom {8}{1}\binom {6}{4}+\binom {10}{1}\binom {8}{4}\binom {6}{1}+\binom {10}{4}\binom {8}{1}\binom {6}{1}$

#### 2. As $2,2,2:$

$=\binom {10}{2}\binom {8}{2}\binom {6}{2}$

#### 3. As $1,2,3:$

$=\binom {10}{1}\binom {8}{2}\binom {6}{3}+\binom {10}{1}\binom {8}{3}\binom {6}{2}+\binom {10}{2}\binom {8}{1}\binom {6}{3}+\binom {10}{2}\binom {8}{3}\binom {6}{1}+\binom {10}{3}\binom {8}{1}\binom {6}{2}+\binom {10}{3}\binom {8}{2}\binom {6}{1}$

$\begin{align}\bf{\text{Total }}&= 18900+4200+1200+10080+8400+5600+15120+7200+20160+14400\\ &= \bf105260\end{align}$

So, the required probability is,
$$\begin{align}P(E) &=1-\frac{105260}{\binom{24}6} \\ &= 1-\frac{105260}{134596} \\ &=1-0.782044 \\ &\simeq \boxed{ 0.2180}\end{align}$$

Thus, the probability that at least one of the shifts will be unrepresented in the sample of workers is $\bf 0.2180$.